# MVC 4/ajax/partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After looking up related StackOverflow topics I did not find any appropriate solution I finally come up to post...
 initially:
ajax works, I do have a server response of the html filled up table partialview, however it is not rendered at the specified  of which id is "QuerySection". scripts bundled:
"~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js", "~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js", "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" as well as jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

what am I doing wrong?

controller's action partialview added filename below

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogsPartial(string[] choices)
    {
        var datebegin = choices[0].Length==0?new DateTime(2014,1,1): DateTime.Parse(choices[0]);
        var dateend = choices[1].Length == 0 ? new DateTime(2150, 1, 1) : DateTime.Parse(choices [1]); 
        var lstLogs = db.Logs.Include("Users").Where(x => x.DateOfAction >= datebegin &&.DateOfAction <= dateend).ToList();
        if (lstLogs.Any())
        {
            return PartialView("LogsPartial", lstLogs);
        }
        else
            return PartialView("LogsPartial",null);

    }
```

partialview >> LogsPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ContiRFQ.Models.Logs>

    @if (Model == null || Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <p>No results found</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>Logs</h2>

            <table>
                <tr>

                    <th>
                        Account
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       Action
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       Date of Action
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.Account)   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Action)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          @item.DateOfAction.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy, HH:mm")  
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }

    </table>
```

}

and the index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {

        var dates = [$('#BeginDate').val(), $('#EndDate').val()];
        var json = JSON.stringify(dates);

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("LogsPartial", "Logs")",

            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: json,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) 
            {
                $('#QuerySection').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.trace();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
 <div id="QuerySection"> </div>
```

Comment: "however it is not rendered at the specified ..... " - what does this mean?

Comment: excuse me.... not rendered in the specified <div> of which id is "QuerySection"

Comment: But it is rendered elsewhere on the page or not at all? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no errors not rendered at all. The IE F12 stuff returns the partialview. deleted browsing history, with no effect. server response : Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: Breakpoint the action method, breakpoint the success and error javascript functions and see where the problem is occuring

Comment: is ajax call working, you check in firebug?

Comment: you can try adding a unique class to div and use that at success function to put partial view html in it, sometime things stuck and experimenting this way gives relief

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the action method to a PartialViewResult (explicitly) instead of an ActionResult. Then you just need to do

```
return PartialView(lstLogs);
```

I am guessing that the OS handles it based on the return type specific in the method signature rather than what you actually return.

Comment: If you look at the html return in by the method, does it contain the _layout html or just what is in the view? You can try adding <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> to appSettings in the web.config if it isn't there already.

Comment: thanks, the section was present in web.config  :( the returned html contains only the partial view content

Comment: Does the html that is passed back contain the "<html>" tags and such or just the content from the partial view?

Comment: the response data returned from the server only contains the html tabular data, basically  only the partial view stuff

Comment: if you are getting the html back from the service, the only thing I can think of is it being a jquery issue. Maybe just use standard javascript. document.getElementById("QuerySection").innerHTML = data;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys, after some hours struggling /trying it turned out that an evident parameter of .ajax function was wrong. datatype:json, though I was expecting html ......

Comment: good, i thought on it but i was confused that datatype is used for data we are posting or the reposne data we are getting, so i did;nt posted answer, because i was myself not sure on it.
but i was right, it was this issue, i was curious about your question asnwer, i marked it as favourite question as well..:)